# Where can I find a database of historical wildfires in the USA back to 1960?

Tags: database

Not sure if it is the right place to post this question but I'd like to know where to find a wildfire database? I don't need any geospatial data.  Just a list of the wildfires that happened in USA from 1960 to present is needed. Wildfires of interest include both human and lightning caused.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear the main focus is on wildfires.  If you are looking for lists of famous structural fires, that should be a separate question.

Comment: Do you know of the existence of [Opendata.se]? (But please don't cross-post)

Comment: I post that the same question there as well however I felt I didn't get enough information so I thought I'd give it a try here.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the [National Interagency Fire Center](https://www.nifc.gov/fireInfo/fireInfo_statistics.html), which keeps statistics in a variety of formats as well as lists of historical fires.  For instance, you can see a list of historically significant fires as far back as 1804 [here](https://www.nifc.gov/fireInfo/fireInfo_stats_histSigFires.html).  In general, the closer you get to present, the more information about fires there is.

Other websites with historical wildfire lists include:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wildfires#North_America) list of large fires
- [USGS](http://wildfire.cr.usgs.gov/firehistory/data.html) spatial data back to 1980 with a viewer [here](http://wildfire.cr.usgs.gov/firehistory/viewer/viewer.htm)
- [NOAA](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/paleoclimatology-data/datasets/fire-history) World Data Center

Comment: That NOAA World Data Center looks good. I will give that a try.